# Mail.app garbles images in newsletters

Tags: macos, mac, apple-mail

I have a problem with Mail.app when receiving emails from Financial sites and the like who use text+graphics for their logos and newsletters.

I have attached an example. This doesn't happen OS wide but its just Mail.app.

Note: I am using Exchange with Mail.app[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Looks like [this blog entry](http://avianbonesyndrome.com/2010/09/07/fix-broken-imap-attachments-in-mail-app/) might be of use.

The "tl;dr" is to rebuild your Inbox folder in order to re-download the images.

Mailbox -> Rebuild